# Making a web request to a web page which requires windows authentication

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, webrequest

I am trying to make a request to a web page using WebRequest class in .net. The url that I am trying to read requires Windows Authentication due to which I get an unauthorised exception. How can I pass a windows credentials to this request so that it can authenticate.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( "http://myapp/home.aspx" );

request.Method = "GET";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "username", "password", "domain" );

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // Raises Unauthorized Exception

this.Response.Write( response.StatusCode );
```

The above code returns the following error.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I noticed one thing while checking the exception details is that the url that I am trying to access is redirecting to a different url which is prompting me to provide the NT login details. I believe that the credentials should get forwarded to this url as well. But apparently it is not happening.

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: Thanks, setting PreAuthenticate to true helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am trying to access a link A passing the windows credentials. Link A then redirects me to link B automatically but does not pass the windows credentials which I had supplied. Hence the error. I did request.AutoRedirect = false, and looped through every time I get location in the header i.e. I do my redirects manually each time passing the windows credentials.

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 52):

You should use [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property to pass the windows credentials to the web service.

If you wish to pass current windows user's credentials to the service then

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

should do the trick. Otherwise use [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytcd70k.aspx) as follows:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain);
```

Comment: As you can see in the code which I have posted, I am using the NetworkCredential class to pass my windows login. But even that is not working.

Comment: Did you put the code later - I don't recall seeing it. Regardless, 401 error means credentials can be wrong or it can also mean that credentials are right but that user does not have access to that URL. I will suggest that you check your service url from browser. If it works from there then it should work with WebRequest as well as.

Comment: I edited the post and included the code. Also, I am able to access the url in the browser with the credentials but not able to do the same using WebRequest.

Comment: Try with request.PreAuthenticate = false; Reasoning is that server is throwing 401 as a challenge response and WebRequest would not respond to the challenge unless this property is false.

Comment: Tough luck! Just last suggestion - use tool such as Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and compare request-response chain from browser (to service) with the same from WebRequest. As you have said that service works from browser, by comparing request-response, you should get the idea where the problem is.

Comment: Check your headers on the `exception.Response` - for me I had issues with my proxy interfering.

Comment: `request.PreAuthenticate` should be true. If you're doing an inner `WebRequest` instead of this `HttpWebRequest`, you have to set `.Credentials` on that object, too.

Answer (score 14):

For authenticating to WebService, use DefaultNetworkCredentials instead of DefaultCredentials:

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: This fixed a problem I've been trying to fix for a week. Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering if it could help to fix my current issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335532/windows-authentication-website-chrome-iis-and-sharepoint-authentication ?
I read contradictory things regarding differences between each of them.
I'll try ASAP.

Answer (score 7):

Using VS2015, `request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` works for me!