# Sending a web request to a page which requires Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, credentials, webrequest

I would like to know is there any other way to send request to windows authenticated application.
 [Making a web request to a web page which requires windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562979/making-a-web-request-to-a-web-page-which-requires-windows-authentication).

The above link worked for me, but I need to send username and password along with every request. I would like to know any other architectural way to Implement this simply.