# SharePoint Redirect users depending AD Attr. and Authenticate them

Tags: vb.net, redirect, sharepoint, credentials

I would like to redirect user depending on their description AD attribute.

I'm building a ASPX page (with vb.net), and I ask them for their credentials.

Then I create a user context like this :

```
Dim user As UserPrincipal
Using ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN", txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
     user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, txtUsername.Text)
End Using
```

So I'm able to test `user.Description`, and I'm able to redirect them to another page with :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(urltoredirect)
```

But as its SharePoint, I redirect them to another site collection, so it's asking for their credentials. Creds that I've just asked them and I have in my code.

Is there a way to send these creds along with the redirection ? To create a kind of SSO ?

P.S: For more details, I'm trying to creating an custom login page, that will redirect user to a EULA Disclaimer & a Change Password page if this is their first visit, and if not, Redirecting them to their site collection according to their Description attribute. This is for extranet purpose.

EDIT1: I gave a try according to [Making a web request to a web page which requires windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562979/making-a-web-request-to-a-web-page-which-requires-windows-authentication) but none if these solutions seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SPUtility you can try one of the SPUtility.Redirect methods,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility_methods.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer, I read some stuffs about these methods, but I can't find where I send the Windows Credentials that ask the site (because it changes site collection while redirecting). I'm creating a kind of login page,  so users enter their credentials in textbox and when they click "OK" I redirect  them depending an AD Attribute